# Quickly/easily render a data.frame containing column(s) of lists in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

It's straight forward to render a data.frame in a shiny app with `renderTable()`.

Is there an equivalent for data.frames that contain one or more list columns? (i.e. columns where elements of the column are themselves lists)

Preferably something that doesn't necessitate changing the dataframe beforehand

Note: we could map over every list column with something like `mutate(new_col = map_chr(list_col, ~ paste0(.x, collapse= ", ")))` but I wish to avoid manually changing columns

Also note: here's a minimal data.frame containing lists

```
df <- structure(list(foo = list(c("foo1", "foo1.1"), "foo2", "foo3"), 
                     bar = list("bar1", "bar2", "bar3")), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DT (datatable) is OK for you, it accepts lists:

```
library(shiny)
## Only run this example in interactive R sessions
df <- structure(list(foo = list(c("foo1", "foo1.1"), "foo2", "foo3"), 
                     bar = list("bar1", "bar2", "bar3")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



if (interactive()) {
  # table example
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               DT::dataTableOutput('table')
        )
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(df)
    }
  )
}
```

[image]